# How does Outlook 2010 deal with remote PST files?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a user that is complaining that his outlook is slow when working remotely. He uses a PST file as well as a connection to Microsoft exchange. The PST is stored on a file server. How does Outlook deal with the PST?

Does Outlook open the remote PST file or does it download a copy of it into a temp directory and deal with it there, or maybe just download it and hold it in memory?

Comment: It opens the file, in the location the file is located, copying the file doesn't make logical sense.

Comment: By opening it, it's going to have to download the whole thing into memory then?

Comment: No, a PST is a specialized container with structure.  (Much like a .zip)

Comment: So, how does it work then? I mean, when you double click a zip file, if it's large and remote, it doesn't just open, there's a period of time where it thinks about it. This guy's PST is 17gb and he's trying to open it over an ADSL2 connection.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook opens the remote PST. But please don't ever use non-local PST files! This leads to corruptions, interruptions and other negative effects. [Please don't do it!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/01/21/network-stored-pst-files-dont-do-it/)